# If a Hamiltonian is quadratic in the ladder operator, why is its time evolution linear in the ladder operator?

Tags: hamiltonian-simulation, unitarity, chemistry, solid-state, dynamics

How can one show that $\hat{U}^\dagger\hat{a}\hat{U}$ (with $\hat{U} =e^{-i\hat{H}t}$) involves only linear orders of the ladder operator, when $H$ is the general quadratic Hamiltonian $(\hat{H} = \alpha (\hat{a}^\dagger)^2+ \beta \hat{a}^\dagger\hat{a}+\alpha^*\hat{a}^2)?$

I have been trying to do it using the Baker-Campbell-Hausdorff formula.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hint: Instead of using the BCH formula in the form usually presented, for example at the [top of this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker%E2%80%93Campbell%E2%80%93Hausdorff_formula), use [this consequence of Hadamard's Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutator#Exponential_identities):

$$\tag{1}
e^{iHt}\hat{a}e^{-iHt} = \hat{a} + [iHt,\hat{a}] + \frac{1}{2!}[iHt,[iHt,\hat{a}] + \cdots
$$

Now substitute $H$ into the right-hand side and evaluate the commutators between $\hat{a}$ and each of the three terms in $H$.

Let's look at the following commutators that appear in the second term:

\begin{align}\tag{2}
[(\hat{a}^\dagger)^2,\hat{a}] &= -2\hat{a}^\dagger\\\tag{3}
[\hat{a}^\dagger \hat{a},\hat{a}] &= -\hat{a}\\\tag{4}
[\hat{a}^2,\hat{a}] &= 0.\\
\end{align}

All commutators appearing in the third term will be commutators of the same form, or of the form $[(\hat{a}^\dagger)^2,\hat{a^\dagger}],[\hat{a}^\dagger \hat{a},\hat{a}^\dagger],[\hat{a}^2,\hat{a}^\dagger] $, which will again be linear.

In the end, you'll only be left with terms linear in $\hat{a}$ and $\hat{a^\dagger}$, but no "quadratic" terms like $\hat{a}^2$.

Answer (score 6):

Use the differential form of the time evolution,
$$dO/dt=i[H, O]\ .$$

Answer (score 2):

Note that
$$[(a^\dagger)^n,a] = -n(a^{\dagger})^{n-1},
\qquad [(a^\dagger)^n a^m,a] = -n (a^\dagger)^{n-1}a^m,
\qquad [a^n,a]=0.$$
Consider an arbitrary function of the mode operators, that we assume be written in normal formal:
$$f(a,a^\dagger) = \sum_{n,m=0}^\infty c_{n,m} (a^\dagger)^n a^m.$$
We know that
$$e^{f(a,a^\dagger)}a e^{-f(a,a^\dagger)} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{k!}\operatorname{ad}(f(a,a^\dagger))^k\cdot a,$$
where $\operatorname{ad}(A)^k\cdot B \equiv [\underbrace{A,...,[A}_k,B]\cdots]$
denotes the operation of taking the repeated commutator of $A$ with $B$.
For example, for $k=2$, $\operatorname{ad}(A)^2\cdot B\equiv [A,[A,B]]$.

We know that
$$[f(a,a^\dagger),a] = -\sum_{n,m\ge 0}c_{n,m} n (a^\dagger)^{n-1} a^m,$$
$$\operatorname{ad}(f(a,a^\dagger))^k\cdot a
= (-1)^k \sum_{n,m\ge0} c_{n,m} \frac{n!}{(n-k)!} (a^{\dagger})^{n-k}a^m.$$
Thus
$$e^{f(a,a^\dagger)}a e^{-f(a,a^\dagger)}
= \sum_{n,m\ge0 } c_{n,m} (a^\dagger-1)^n a^m
= f(a, a^\dagger-1). $$

This shows you explicitly that properties of $f$ such as its being quadratic permain in $e^f a e^{-f}$. Thus, in particular, you get your result by choosing $f=-iH t$.